# Why is my dev server faster than a much more powerful RDS?

Tags: mysql, performance, migration, amazon-rds

I'm running a huge data migration. Probably ~100 million rows total across a few dozen tables.

There is a lot of reformatting. About 50% of it is done through PHP while the rest uses `INSERT INTO... SELECT FROM` statements with multiple joins.

When I run the script on my dev server (MySQL server is `localhost`), it takes about 2 hours and 14 minutes total. This machine has 8 GB of RAM, 200 GB storage, and a 4-core 3.1 GHz CPU.

I set up an EC2 instance and an RDS in the same zone (`us-east-1a`). The RDS is a `db.r3.2xlarge` instance (vCPU - 8 (cores?), ECU 26, 61 GB RAM, 100 GB storage). I SSH into the EC2 instance and run the script. The PHP portion took 70-80% longer. I expected that, because of network latency connecting to an RDS vs. localhost.

What's more disappointing is that the pure MySQL INSERT queries also took longer. Some of them were the same speed, some were a little faster, but overall they were 35% slower.

The IOPS seemed really low, and the InnoDB buffer usage as well. It really seemed like it wasn't using the resources it has.

[image]

Any suggestions? Is this something that Provisioned IOPS could help with?

---

**Update**

Different `innodb_*` variables:

```
Variable         | Dev server   | RDS
-----------------|--------------|------------
buffer_pool_size | 128 M        | 44 G
flush_method     | (blank)      | O_DIRECT
log_file_size    | 48 M         | 128 M
version          | 5.6.33       | 5.6.19
```

Comment: Sorry I kept deleting and undeleting this because some of the queries were faster than others. But overall the MySQL portion was 35% slower

Comment: What information have you been able to get our of the sys table as far as analyzing inserts? have you looked at any instrumentation to compare performance on the production versus the dev servers?

Comment: What values are different in `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'innodb%';`?

Comment: @RickJames there wasn't much different, I added to the question

Comment: @JPeck89 not much I'm afraid. Only using MySQL Workbench to watch the server stats (in the screenshot) as the queries are running

Comment: Are the numbers on the graphs averages?  Or peaks?  Or top of the graph?  Or last value?

Comment: RDS has SSDs?  Dev has spinning drives?

Comment: @RickJames yes, RDS = SSD, dev = HDD. The numbers are from a moment in time, but they reflect about the average while the large INSERT queries were running

Answer (score 2):

Looks like my initial theory was correct.

A standard RDS is capped at 3 IOPS per GB of storage, hence why my writes were hovering around 332 on a 100 GB instance. Not sure how they went *over* 300; maybe Amazon is not strict about it or maybe MySQL Workbench just had latency and calculated it slightly off.

Anyways we launched a new RDS with provisioned IOPS set to 1,000. Now the queries are running 3x faster than they were before.

It does seem strange to me that the limit is based on the storage size. Those two aren't necessarily directly related in my opinion.

Comment: A guess on tying limits together:  Simplicity in provisioning, sales, etc.

Comment: A guess on "how the IOPs went over 300":  Being more strict would probably involve low level hacks into the I/O, and would probably impact the performance more than is worth the effort.